# A module doesn't see Public variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Excuse me, something is wrong again
Standard module :

```
Public ws1 As Worksheet
Public rCopy As Range
```

Workbook_Open :

```
Set ws1 = Sheets("abc")
Set rCopy = ws1.Range("A1")
```

Third module :

```
ws1.Select ' Error
rCopy.Select ' Error
```

Please help.

Comment: Make sure the code in the third workbook runs after Workbook_Open... and that nothing has reset it in between :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted *does* work.

One reason you may get an error is if you have been debugging your code and at some point had an error and stopped excution, the public variables will no longer be set.  You simply need to run the `Workbook_Open` sub again (you can run it from the IDE, using `F5`)

Note, you should take the advise from you last question and use `Set ws1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("abc")`.  If you don't you run the risk that `ws1` will get set to sheet `abc` in another workbook, because as written it is equivalent to `Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("abc")`

Answer (score 3):

If the code in the 3rd module is not being called as a result of some event that happens *after* Workbook_Open, the two variables are still uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

And what about private members and property?

```
Option Explicit

Private m_mySheet As Worksheet
Private m_myRange As Range

Public Property Get MySheet() As Worksheet
    If (m_mySheet Is Nothing) Then
        Set m_mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("abc")
    End If
    Set MySheet = m_mySheet
End Property

Public Property Get MyRange() As Range
    If (m_myRange Is Nothing) Then
        Set m_myRange = MySheet.Range("A1")
    End If
    Set MyRange = m_myRange
End Property

Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Debug.Print MyRange.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Your code is rather unclear to me, but I'll take some time to analyze it.

Comment: @Alegro: for better understanding, in your code you will not use public variables ws1 or rCopy but public properties like e.g. MyRange. If you call property MyRange then m_myRange is checked first and if it is Nothing, then it is set. So this way it should be avoided that MyRange is Nothing when you need it :-). Hope it helps, regards Dan.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. You are very kind. I see the point now. Very good Trick.